# cambiar de estado radioButton generados por codigo?

Tags: android, android-studio, radiobutton, radiogroup

Estoy generando una serie de RadioButton por codigo y no he sido capas de cambiar el estado cuando un RadioButton pierde el estado de checked.
actualmente cuando checked uno y paso a checked otro, ambos quedan con el estado de checked.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
lo que trato de hacer es que no quede con ese estado algo como esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
la manera como estoy creando los RadioButton es la siguiente.

```html
     //Creo un LinearLayaout como contenedor de los radioButton
     rl = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.content_radioGroup);

        // Initialize a new RadioGroup
        radioGroup_edad = new RadioGroup(getContext());
        radioGroup_edad.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
        //ciclo para crear los radiobutton
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {

            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getContext());
            radioButton.setText("r " + i);
            radioButton.setId(i);

            radioButton.setButtonDrawable(R.color.transparent);
            radioButton.setWidth(100);

            radioButton.setTextSize(16);
            radioButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
            radioButton.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

            radioGroup_edad.addView(radioButton);

        }

        // Finally, add the RadioGroup to main layout
        rl.addView(radioGroup_edad);

        radioGroup_edad.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
//al activarse este evento obtengo el checkedId al cual le voy a poner el estado de check
               RadioButton radiobutton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(checkedId);
                radiobutton.setTextSize(24);
                radiobutton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorWhite));
            }
        });
```

Alguna idea de como puedo lograr esto.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: La forma en que comúnmente se realiza esto cambiar las propiedades default a todos los elementos dentro del RadioGroup y al que seleccionaste aplicar los cambios, agregue respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con el siguiente metodo:

```
private void setupRadioGroup() {
final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
    rg.addView(rb[i]); 
    rb[i].setText("Test");
}
ll.addView(rg);//you add the whole RadioGroup to the layout
ll.addView(submit); 
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
            rg.removeView(rb[i]);
        }  
        ll.removeView(submit);
        Questions();
    }
});   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Como opción puedes cambiar las propiedades default a todos los `radiobutton` contenidos en el `RadioGroup` excepto al que seleccionaste:

```
 radioGroup_edad.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int checkedId) {

            RadioButton radiobutton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(checkedId);
            //Obtienes los elementos dentro del RadioGroup.
            for (int j = 0; j < radioGroup.getChildCount(); j++) {
              if(j != checkedId){//Change other radiobuttons to default properties
                 radioButton.setTextSize(16);
                 radioButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
              }else{ //* Elemento seleccionado.
                 //al activarse este evento obtengo el checkedId al cual le voy a poner el estado de check
                radiobutton.setTextSize(24);
                radiobutton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorWhite));
              }

            }
        });
```

De esta forma cuando des clic a un elemento los demás regresaran a sus propiedades default.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero no hay una forma de hacerlo sin tener que recorrer los radiobuttons, por que e intentado hacerlo con los drawable con los estados, pero desde aqui no puedo cambiar los colores de texto, solo me da para cambiar el background